# How to compose two Flows side-by-side?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, akka, akka-stream

Is there an Akka streams combinator for doing the following (or something to that effect)? (Let's call it `and` for now.)

```
(flow1: Flow[I, O, Mat]).and[O2](flow2: Flow[I, O2, Mat]): Flow[I, (O, O2), Mat]
```

The semantics would be that whatever the source, its elements will be passed to both `Flow`s, and their outputs will be combined into a new `Flow` as a tuple. (For those familiar with arrows from category theory flavoured functional programming, I am looking for something like `&&&`.)

There are two combinators in the library that looked relevant, namely `zip` and `alsoTo`. But the former accepts a `SourceShape`, and the latter, a `SinkShape`. Neither would admit a `GraphShape`. Why is this the case?

My use case is something like following:

```
someSource
  .via(someFlowThatReturnsUnit.and(Flow.apply))
  .runWith(someSink)
```

Failing to find something like `.and`, I modified my original `Flow` like this:

```
someSource
  .via(someFlowThatDoesWhateverItWasDoingEarlierButNowAlsoEmitsInputsAsIs)
  .runWith(someSink)
```

This works, but I am looking for a cleaner, more compositional solution.

Comment: A Flow is not strictly 1:1 (1 input for 1 output) so such a generic combinator would be tricky. (You can use GraphDSL and use Broadcast + Merge)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Notice**

As Viktor Klang noted in the comments: zipping into a `Tuple2[O,O2]` is only viable when it is known that both flows, `flow1` & `flow2`, are 1:1 with respect to input element count and output element count.

**Graph Based Solution**

A tuple construct can be created inside of a [Graph](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-graphs.html#constructing-graphs).  In fact, your question almost perfectly matches the introductory example:

[image]

Extending the sample code in the link, you can use [Broadcast](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/Broadcast.html) and [Zip](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/Zip$.html)

```
val g = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder: GraphDSL.Builder[NotUsed] =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._
  val in = Source(1 to 10)
  val out = Sink.ignore

  val bcast = builder.add(Broadcast[Int](2))

  val merge = builder.add(Zip[Int, Int]()) //different than link

  val f1, f2, f4 = Flow[Int].map(_ + 10)

  val f3 = Flow[(Int, Int)].map(t => t._1 + t._2) //different than link

  in ~> f1 ~> bcast ~> f2 ~> merge ~> f3 ~> out
              bcast ~> f4 ~> merge
  ClosedShape
})//end RunnableGraph.fromGraph
```

**Somewhat Hacky Stream Solution**

If you are looking for a pure stream solution, it is possible using intermediate streams but the `Mat` would not be maintained and it involves materialization of 2 streams for each input element:

```
def andFlows[I, O, O2] (maxConcurrentSreams : Int)
                       (flow1: Flow[I, O, NotUsed], flow2: Flow[I, O2, NotUsed])
                       (implicit mat : Materializer, ec : ExecutionContext) : Flow[I, (O, O2), _] = 
  Flow[I].mapAsync(maxConcurrentStreams){ i =>

    val o  : Future[O]  = Source
                           .single(i)
                           .via(flow1)
                           .to(Sink.head[O])
                           .run()

    val o2 : Future[O2] = Source
                           .single(i)
                           .via(flow2)
                           .to(Sink.head[O2])
                           .run()

    o zip o2
  }//end Flow[I].mapAsync
```

**Generic Zipping**

If you want to make this zipping generic, for most Flows, then the output type will have to be `(Seq[O], Seq[O2])`.   This type can be generated by  using `Sink.seq` instead of `Sink.head` in the above `andFlows` function:

```
def genericAndFlows[I, O, O2] (maxConcurrentSreams : Int)
                              (flow1: Flow[I, O, NotUsed], flow2: Flow[I, O2, NotUsed])
                              (implicit mat : Materializer, ec : ExecutionContext) : Flow[I, (Seq[O], Seq[O2]), _] = 
  Flow[I].mapAsync(maxConcurrentStreams){ i =>

    val o  : Future[Seq[O]]  = Source
                                .single(i)
                                .via(flow1)
                                .to(Sink.seq[O])
                                .run()

    val o2 : Future[Seq[O2]] = Source
                                .single(i)
                                .via(flow2)
                                .to(Sink.seq[O2])
                                .run()

    o zip o2
  }//end Flow[I].mapAsync
```